# How can I validate the file type selected from an input element of type file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to allow users to upload an image by using the html below

```html
<input class="file-upload" id="imagepath" name="imagepath" type="file" accept="image/x-png,image/jpeg"  />
```

Is there any way to show a validation message if a user selects a file that is not of the correct type using JS/JQuery?

I understand that the 'accept' attribute restricts what a user will see when they are viewing the file explorer however this can be changed using the drop down, to 'All files'.

Comment: Hi @Thomas Clague, you can use jquery validation plugin

Comment: unfortunately I am not able to use any plug ins

Answer (score 3):

You can fetch the extension of an uploaded file.

```
var files = event.target.files;
var filename = files[0].name;
var extension = files[0].type;
```

And apply the check and allow whichever file type you wanted to allow. Say for images stuff.

```
if(extension == "jpeg" || extension == "jpg") {
   //do you code
} else {
   //display an error
}
```

Comment: And what would be the correct way to display a validation message? adding label with a class of .hide with display: none; and then toggling it?

Comment: I dont think if there is any standard way to do this. It completely depends on your requirement. You can display an alert stating incorrect format. Or you can reset the field and display some label next to your file input indicating the same doing that hide/show thing..

Answer (score 2):

I think J D already gave you a solid answer on how to check the file type.

I looked around and found [an example on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#Examples) which I modified a bit. It exists of a list of accepted file types, like the one in your `accept` attribute and a function which will check if the type of a file matches the ones in your `accept` attribute.

The `isValidFileType` accepts a `File` and and `array` as arguments which then will check if the `File.type` is present in the `types` array. If it is it will return true and not it will return false.

Same principles as J D described but with a functional programming approach.

```
// The input element.
const imagePath = document.getElementById('imagepath');

// List of accepted file types, gotten from your input's accept property.
const acceptedFileTypes = imagePath.accept.split(','); // ['image/jpeg', 'image/x-png']

// Check if file has the correct type.
const isValidFileType = (file, types) => types.some(type => type === file.type);
```

So on your form element you should attach a change event listener. And in that listener loop over all of the files and check if they have the correct extension.

```
imagePath.addEventListener('change', (event) => {

    // Check if every file has the accepted extension.
    const filesAccepted = event.target.files.every(file => 
        isValidFileType(file, acceptedFiles)
    );

    if (filesAccepted) {
        // Files are accepted
    } else {
        // Files are not accepted.
    }

});
```

Although J D's example is a lot more compact and to the point, this example provides reusability and prevents you from writing the same code twice, or more. Also extending the list of accepted types is as easy as adding them to the `accept` attribute of the HTML element.

Comment: I dont think he is allowing multiple file uploads, so why to use loop..

Comment: Because `event.target.files` is an array. Hardcoding the selection of the first key in the array makes the code usable **only** if the user can upload a single file. But if it might change to a multi file upload the code would still run without any modification.

Comment: If we are sure that there wont be multiple files then you can refer it that way. And looking at his html i cant see its allowing multiple files. So its better to avoid looping. If multiple support is there then agree with your code.

Comment: I can see where you coming from and agree with you about when only a single file will ever be uploaded, you should write it as such. Still I would recommend writing your code in a robust way that will handle multiple scenarios can be reused when possible. But, that's just an opinion of mine. I've upvoted your solution.

Comment: Seems difference in opinions. Upvoted yours too.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks For the help guys,

This is the solution I went with in the end and works perfectly

```html
<!--HTML-->
<div id="fileErrorMessage" class="hide" >file type is not suuported</div>
<input class="some-class" id="imagepath" name="imagepath" type="file" accept="image/x-png,image/jpeg"  />
```

```css
/*css*/
#fileErrorMessage {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

```js
//JavaScript

    $('#imagepath').on('change', function (event) {
        var files = event.target.files;
        Array.from(files).forEach(x => {
            if (!x.type.includes("jpeg") && !x.type.includes("jpg") && !x.type.includes("png")) {
                $("#fileErrorMessage").removeClass("hide");
                $('#imagepath').val('');
            }
            else if (!$("#fileErrorMessage").hasClass("hide")) {
                $("#fileErrorMessage").addClass("hide");
            }

        });
    });
```